# Is there a word for a person with only one head?

Tags: single-word-requests, neologisms, construction

Reading [this article](http://www.douglasadams.com/dna/19990901-00-a.html) by the fantastic Douglas Adams I came across this interesting quote:

> ‘[I]nteractivity’ is one of those neologisms that Mr Humphrys likes to dangle between a pair of verbal tweezers, but the reason we suddenly need such a word is that during this century we have for the first time been dominated by non-interactive forms of entertainment: cinema, radio, recorded music and television... We didn’t need a special word for interactivity in the same way that we don’t (yet) need a special word for people with only one head.

This got me thinking — not just about what that word might be (unikef? monocap?), but also about how new words are constructed.

My two first thoughts above were that the word would be constructed from either Greek or Latin roots (mono and uni, respectively), and I assume that most newly constructed words would follow a similar structure. That is - they would take previously prescribed pieces of a language (classical or otherwise) and shape those pieces to fit the needs of the new word.

But which language would be more likely? Greek? Or Latin? Or, since the concept of having to describe someone with only one head antedates both of these languages by so much, would it be inappropriate for a new word to have a classical root?

I would appreciate it if any readers who do have multiple heads could let us know authoritatively how you refer to us one-headed folks.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The point that a word should make is that it has to be an adequate symbol for what it represents.

This is, in essence, arbitrary and pragmatic and what ever work (as a symbol) will make its way into memories and experience of individuals, then a subculture (jargon) and then culture (spreading from common spoken use to use in periodical publications to the moment these words are added to dictionaries).

It can follow patterns from Greek or Latin, and you will find many example in this and last century — we had to invent many new words to deal with advance of information technology.

If you read up on [neologism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neologism) you will find other ways of constructing new words mentioned — combining existing words (regardless of etymology), abbreviating, rhyming, etc..

- [urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/) almost exclusively shows neologisms (even fictional)
- [Here](http://rdues.bcu.ac.uk/neologisms.shtml) you can see new words in journals
- You can also look at lists of words added to a dictionary, such as [this](http://www.merriam-webster.com/info/new_words.htm) *sample* from Merriam-Webster

As you examine these lists you will see progression from less adopted words to more standard words and you might see some patterns that make them accepted into the language.

EDIT:

- There is [polycephaly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycephaly) - which refers to general condition of having more then one head
- In case of words prefixed with *poly-*, the usual counterpart is *mono-* and so your best bet is **monocephaly**

After I constructed the word, I looked it up and it exists:

> **mon·o·ce·phal·ic**
>
> Bearing one flower head, as in the
>   scape of a dandelion.

Answer (score 37):

A variant would be [monocephalous](http://www.wordnik.com/words/monocephalous):

> 1. Having only one head; in botany, bearing a single capitulum or head.
> 2. Specifically, having the character of a monocephalus.

or [monocephalus](http://www.wordnik.com/words/monocephalus):

> – noun
>
> 1. In teratol., a double monster having only one head but two bodies.
>    Also called syncephalus.

See also [syncephalus](http://www.wordnik.com/words/syncephalus):

> – noun
>
> 1. In teratology, a double monster with more or less fusion of the heads:
>    same as monocephalus.

Comment: I don't think monocephalus on syncephalus quite fit; both depend on double bodies, unlike monocephalous.  The original question assumed double heads on a single body.  But thanks for "teratology".  Now I need to engineer a conversation into which it can be forced...

Comment: what about unicephalot(us|ic)?

Comment: @PSU "What is this teratology?" (use generously in place of "sorcery" or of course, "monstrosit") haha

Comment: You could use *monocephalus* facetiously for a beast with one head (just as you sometimes hear *biclops* for a beast with two eyes in contrast to *cyclops*), but *monocephalous* seems more fitting in general.

Answer (score 28):

I wish I had come sooner. You see, my good reptilian sister was to put your race in its place, but, alas, she was slain by a sacrilegious buffoon:

[image]

As a classicist, I'd begin with what words the Ancients used themselves. The following two are (most probably) the only options in both languages—that is, *Lewis & Short* and *Liddell, Scott, Jones* have only these words.

Greek: **[μονοκέφαλος](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0057:entry=monoke/falos)**

- From this, correct formations would be *monocephalic*, *monocephalous*, and ?*monocephalus*. The latter is not used in English, I think, but only in medicine or biology, which use Latin in those cases, not English (they'd be italicized). The first one being the most common and analogous to most other existing *-cephal-* words, I'd pick ***monocephalic***.

Latin: ***[uniceps](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=uniceps)***

- From this, correct formations would be *unicapital* and *unicipitous*. Because neither form exists so far in either the Oxford English Dictionary or Google Ngrams, I'd simply stick with *monocephalic* to describe your pathetic race.

---

New words based on a word from another language normally follow the way in which older English words from the same stem/root have been formed. Whenever English first adopts a foreign stem, it is converted into an English stem to make appropriate derivations from. This is to some degree an arbitrary process, and there are often several methods by which it may come about; in most cases, one or more of those become established soon after the word is first adopted, and new words based on the same stem are from then on expected to follow the pattern. If a new stem to be converted is similar to a stem that has already been converted, formation usually proceeds analogously as far as possible.

It is generally preferred that a compound word be made from stems that all come from the same language, though hybrids may be necessary if no single language can provide all parts, or if the language that is used in related words cannot provide them. It should first be checked whether a compound already exists in the language of origin, in which case that should be adopted as a whole; only if such does not exist should one create a new compound.

Comment: +1, dear sir if you had came sooner my answer would not be on top. highly educational, not only in the quality of references, but from formatting to style.

Comment: @Unreason: You are too gracious. I suppose a picture works, but quite honestly I only posted an answer because I felt obliged to make my presence known, as I had little to add to your *monocephalic*.

Comment: +1 for username. Although you really blew the opportunity to directly address the asker "I would appreciate it if any readers who do have multiple heads could let us know authoritatively how you refer to us one-headed folks."

Comment: @PatrickM: Haha, yes! You poor monocephalics...

Answer (score 23):

We don’t have a specific word yet for *people* with one head, but botanists and other similar scientists have long needed such words.  Google Ngrams shows that **one-headed**, **monocephalous** and **monocephalic** have all been used significantly over the years.  (Edit: bill weaver points out in comments that **single-headed** is indeed more frequent than any of these.)   *Monocephalus* also appears, but only very rarely as an English noun: it seems to always be either in scientific names of plants, or else a typo for *monocephalous*.  *Unicapital*, *monocephalon*, and various other variations I tried found no hits.

Speculating, I think *one-headed* would probably dominate everyday use.  As a noun-form, *one-head* is obvious, but could easily become pejorative/derogatory; *one-headed person/people* would then be the politically correct phrase.  *Monocephalous* would, like many similar classical formations, remain mostly associated with medical usage.

[image: ngrams graph of one-headed, monocephalous, monocephalic, monocephalus]

Comment: This is very interesting: it seems that there has been a growing need to describe things as one-headed since the turn of the last century. Which coincides with the rise in popularity of the word "Mutant". I wonder if I'm missing something...

Comment: Newbie question: Why did you exclude "single - headed" from the Ngram? http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=one+-+headed%2Csingle+-+headed%2Cmonocephalous%2Cmonocephalic%2Cmonocephalus&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: @bill weaver: because I didn’t think of it :-P  Good call!

Comment: ah, ok. Thanks! It seriously dampens those other signals, so i thought there might be something about that phrase i was missing... maybe a meaning i was overlooking or some such.

Comment: Impressive that you were able to keep at least some focus on the explicit *literal* question (what's a word for *people* with only one head?).  My vote for a noun form would be monocephalite.

Answer (score 9):

How about something like "unicapital".

From **unus** *L. one* + **capitis** *L. head*

> The unicapital inhabitants of the Sol System consume comparatively few facial tissues.

Comment: The *caput*/*capitalis* Latin root is used in English in words like capital, decapitation, … The Greek root *kephale* is used for scientific terms.

Comment: @F'x : Ahh, good info.

Comment: … I've now made a full-length answer to show the difference between the uses of the two roots.

Comment: …: I don’t know whether to read your example sentence as about blowing noses, or eating brains…

Answer (score 8):

Certain activists in the polycephalic community refer to monocephs as "cephalotypical".

I know it stings. It's meant to.

Answer (score 5):

The Greek root for the head is *kephalē*. It is the root used for scientific terms, including the following English words (dates are from [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=kephale&searchmode=none)):

- hydrocephalus (1660’s)
- acephalous (1731)
- cephalopod (1826)
- encephalitis (1843)
- microcephalic (1856)
- cephalization (1864)

It's also seen in [Bucephalus](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Bucephalus), the name of Alexander the Great’s horse.

---

The Latin root for head is *caput*, with *capitalis* meaning “of the head” or “related to the head”. Common words were derived from it, through Old French, early in the evolution of the language (modern creations favour the Greek root *kephale*):

- capital (adjective first, then the noun)
- cattle
- capitulation
- decapitate
- occipital
- captain, corporal
- chapter

---

Finally, it is worth noting that both Greek *kephale* and Latin *caput* derive from the same Proto-Indo European root, *kaput-* (which means “head”, of course).

Comment: The Latin word comes from the same Indo-European root as the English word "head." But Wiktionary says that the Greek word comes from a different root *ǵʰebʰ-l-. Normally, Greek ph does not correspond to Latin p.

Answer (score 3):

I'd run with "cykopf", taken from "cyclops", and the German "kopf" for "head" of course.

Comment: "cyclops" basically means "wheel-eye." So the parts of your word mean "wheel head." Of course, portmanteaus don't need to combine in a logical fashion, but it does seem like a bizarre term.

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of situation, the first prominent person with two heads would come up with a word now and then to describe his/her single-headed counterparts. Whichever one caught on with the masses would be the word.

Since that person would most certainly be Zaphod Beeblebrox, I'd expect the word roots to be from intergalactic slang, alcoholic drink names, or some combination of the two. The word would definitely not Latin-based or anything sophisticated.

Comment: You mean it might be a stupid meaningless word like 'Morlocks', or 'Forshizzle'?

Comment: @Doug - exactly, but I would expext some negative form of the adjective froody, like frood-prude. Maybe Frood Blaster.