# “Blow your heads off ” or “blow your head off ”

Tags: expressions

Is it *heads* or *head*? Google told me both are okay. What do you think?

> I will blow your head[s] off if you don't tell me.

Comment: It simply depends if there is more than 1 person. (I didn't down vote btw)

Comment: but see http://english.stackexchange.com/q/26742/8019

Comment: @TimLymington: which means we could have more than one heads, at least figuratively.

Comment: Or, there could be many people with one head. Many people seem to share one brain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply depends if there is more than one person. ie. plural.

I think in most cases you would be threatening just one person, so it would more likely be without the "s".

> I will blow your head off if you don't tell me.

If you are in fact threatening a group of people and are prepared to blow all their heads off then you need the "s". And "you" is now plural.

> I will blow your heads off if you don't tell me.

Comment: I thought the same, but that doesnt seem to be the case. Here is a qoute from a book: *Where is she? I know you know." Wilma now spoke in her own voice.“Tell me or I'll blow your heads off.” “Where's who?” the Kid said, not putting together the situation, and castigating me with his eyes as though it were my fault. I suppose it was. “Suzy,” I clarified, before the Kid said something to infuriate her.*

Comment: Sorry, I think there are two people in the conversation. I overlooked the whole thing.

Comment: Yes, I think there must be more than one person, or possibly an unknown number of people (one or more) and they are assuming there is more than one?

Comment: Right. That's what I figured. Thanks for the answer.