# What is the antonym of "armiger"?

Tags: antonyms

I wonder to know is there any word which is the antonym of "armiger"?

- armiger: one entitled to armorial bearings ([Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/armiger)).

> A noble who has not a coat of arms is called a ___

There is a possible heraldic system in ancient Iran. Some nobles in ancient Iran had arms and some of them had not. I need the word to describe those without arms.

Comment: So you want a word that means "everybody who is not entitled to armorial bearings", in other words, a word that describes probably 99.99% of the world population? Why do you think there should be a word to describe a completely common, normal, default situation that applies in almost all cases as beings "special" because some extremely rare exception does not apply? I would not expect there to be a special word for someone who has two legs, even though there may be a word for someone with only one leg.

Comment: Related: [Is there a name for someone with only one head?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/26742/8019).

Comment: You need to edit your question and clarify. Comments can be deleted without warning, and users will answer the question, not the extra information in the comments.

Comment: How about "unheralded"?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for **commoner** ?

- Definition: One of the common people, a person without noble rank or title.
- Example: The king feared that had Prince Bertil married a commoner, the royal dynasty's survival would be jeopardised

EDIT: *response provided before question clarification, i.e. noble without arm*

Comment: In Europe (France for instance), all armigers aren't necessarily noble. Hoxever, some particularities were distinguishing noble and commoner arms.

Comment: Yes, I do know.

Comment: As the arms are considered (in Europe) as one of the main attributes of nobility, I am not sure that the word you are looking for exists in English.