# Which animals can and can't be prefixed with "she-"?

Tags: prefixes, animals

I've heard of "she-wolf" (partially from mythology, partially from pop music), and I'm wondering which animals "she-" can and can't be used on.

Wiktionary mentions a variety of animals (she-ass, she-bear, she-cat, she-dog, she-elephant, she-goat, she-monkey, she-wolf) but apart from them all being placental mammals, there doesn't seem to be anything in common between them - some are domesticated, some aren't, some are carnivorous, some are vegetarian.

Which animals can "she-" and can't be used on, and why?

I tried looking for information on this, but came up with http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/115063-she-horse and http://lydbury.co.uk/forum/index.php?topic=2148.0 which don't fully answer my question.

The online etymology dictionary doesn't have any information about [she](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=she) as a prefix.

Comment: Can you give me an animal that can't be prefixed by *she-*? Certainly *she-wolf* is used a lot more often than *she-lion*, while *wolf* and *lion* are roughly equal in frequency. But is *she-lion* incorrect?

Comment: How about "she- Portuguese man-of-war"?  Despite its nomenclature, a distinctly asexual beast.

Comment: @PeterShor [she-New Mexico whiptail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Mexico_whiptail) would be rather [monocephalic](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26742/is-there-a-word-for-a-person-with-only-one-head)-esque.

Comment: It should probably not be used, except in one of the already-familiar combinations, and then only in relatively informal contexts.

Comment: This is archaic usage, be careful to use it only when appropriate.

Comment: _She-shells_ sound like something that the sea sells when a speaker's tongue gets really twisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This site](http://www.english-for-students.com/The-Male-and-Female-Names-of-Animals.html)  has the following list of female terms with "she-":

**she-ass** (mule), **she-bear**, **she-chuck** (woodchuck), **she-fox**, **she-goat**, **she-lion** (lion & cougar).

**She-bear** is mentioned in [English Bibles](http://biblehub.com/2_kings/2-24.htm)

Oxford English Dictionary 2d Ed. has a subsense of a dictionary entry "she":

9. Female. Applied to animals, as in **she-ass**, **she-bear**, **she-wolf** (also *fig.*), etc.; **she-dog**, chiefly *transf.* =  bitch 2; **she-dragon**, a female dragon; also *transf.*; **she-lion** *slang*, a punning distortion of ‘shilling’; **she-stock**, **-stuff** *U.S.*, female cattle.

OAD 2d Ed. also has **she-ape**, **she-raven**, **she-sparrow**, **she-cat**, **she-dingo**, **she-panther**, **she-lion**, **she-tiger**, **she-pigs**, **she-whales**, 
**she-fairies**, **she-devil**, **she-griffin**, **she-giant**, **she-furies**, 
**she-cousin**, **she-pensioners**, **she-priest**, **she-bishop**, **she-waiter**, **she-surgeon**, **she-slaves**, **she-fool** in the definitions and/or examples.

Webster's Unabridged 3d Ed. has **she-ass** as a dictionary entry, and **she-goat**, **she-fox**, **she-serpent**, **she-monster**, **she-demon**, **she-wolf**, **she-mule** in the definitions.

Besides, Unabridged M-W has **[she-crab](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/she-crab)** "an immature female blue crab".

Comment: Interesting. Many of these have more common species-specific female terms, like "jenny" (ass), "vixen," "nanny goat," "lioness."

Answer (score 2):

The prefix "she-" isn't listed in the dictionary.  The only "she-" animal that is listed in the dictionary is a "[she-wolf](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/she-wolf)."  There are no other "she-" animals listed.

The OED, while it doesn't list "she-bear" separately, it does list it as one of the two possibilities of "she-," along with "she-wolf," under the definition of "[she](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/she?q=she-#she__13)."

Comment: Isn't *she* in *shemale* prefix? Oh, male is not an animal. :-)

Comment: @Rathony : "She-male," "she-devil," and a handful of others all have their own entries.  I didn't mention them because they're not animals *per se*.

Comment: If you Google *she fox*, you get 38,000 hits. I mean, I don't think its number is limited. There could be many more.

Comment: That's actually not very many, especially since there's an animation character named "She-Fox."

Comment: [She dog](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/she-dog) and [she-cat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/she-cat)...

Comment: Lol.  I think we all know what that word is.  She-deer?  Oh, wait, that's a doe.  She-lion?  Oh, wait, that's a lioness.  A she-wolf is a she-wolf.  There's no other word for it.

Comment: I mean it would be better to include those words as just possible words that could be made with "she".

Comment: Why?  They can't be made with *she-*?  *She-* isn't even a thing by itself.  It's not a prefix.  I'd get downvoted for listing nonwords.

Comment: You said, "There are no other "she-" animals listed." But I think its potential is limitless.

Comment: Be that as it may, that thought can't be backed up with sources.  How many times have I heard that this is a site about sources?  You have to have references.  It just doesn't hold up.

Comment: I posted Wiktionary links for she dog and she cat.

Comment: I don't list Wiktionary links anymore.  I get scathed every time because anyone can input anything they want to Wiktionary.  I could go there and input "she-Rathony" and then you'd have another you could list.  ;-)

Comment: I like she-Rathony. Some definitions of Wiktionary are better than other top dictionaries. Their quality is getting better. We should avoid further comments. +1)

Comment: @BenjaminHarman A quick search reveals that a female wolf can be referred to as a bitch as well as a she-wolf, so there is another word for it.

Comment: Google's "guestimate" of "about 30,800 results" for [**she-camel**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22she-camel%22) may be a bit optimistic, but there are certainly enough instances to make it hard to deny that it's a "valid word".

Comment: @FumbleFingers : That's not because "she-camel" represents female camels.  That's because "She-Camel of God" is a proper name.  She-Camel of God was the name of a miraculous camel in Arabian lore and from the Qur'an.  She-Camel of God was a miraculous camel sent by God to the people of Thamud, in Arabia, when they demanded their prophet Saleh or Sahlay to ask God for a miracle. The narrative and story of She-Camel of God is recorded in the Qur'an.  A female camel is a *cow*.

Comment: @Benjamin: As my hero [Russell Hoban](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mcxaAAAAMAAJ&q=%22She-Camel+of+God%22&dq=%22She-Camel+of+God%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y) points out, *Those foolish Thamud people are often referred to in the Quran and thus are we reminded that not only is **every she-camel the she-camel of God,** but every other animal and all of us as well, we are all creatures of God.* Clearly the *first* instance of ***she-camel*** there generically references all female camels, even if the second one is a "proper noun".

Comment: @FumbleFingers : You are *too* funny!  That's hilarious.  "Not only is every she-camel the She-Camel of God..."  That's got to be the funniest thing I've read all day.

Comment: If you're not familiar with Russell Hoban, I commend [*Riddley Walker*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riddley_Walker) to you. It's not a children's book at all - it's written phonetically in an imaginary dialect that works so well that after a bit you stop noticing it. But he really has an excellent grasp of the limits of English, as well as an incredibly fertile imagination and a willingness to explore almost any subject matter.